# Business banking insurance above FSCS £85,000

Tags: united-kingdom, banking, savings, insurance

In the UK, the Financial Services Compensation Scheme (FSCS) provides insurance for bank deposits up to £85,000. Is there an insurance (or financial product) that provides coverage above this threshold?

There is a helpful answer to a similar question about personal savings: [UK - What are the safest options to keep more than the FSCS limit in a bank/investment company?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/115562/uk-what-are-the-safest-options-to-keep-more-than-the-fscs-limit-in-a-bank-inve)

Here I'm specifically interested in covering the risk from bank insolvency, for a **business bank account**.